# Fastest way to check if a value or list of values is a subset of a list in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, cython

I have a very large list of lists called `main_list`, holding about 13 million lists, with each of these lists holding 6 numbers. I'm looking for a way to filter out any list that doesn't contain certain values. For example, to create a new list of lists that include only lists with the values of 4 and 5 my code works as following:

```
and_include = []
temp_list=[4,5]
for sett in main_list:
    if set(temp_list).issubset(sett):
        and_include.append(sett)
```

This takes about 5 seconds to run which can be quite annoying for frequent use so I was wondering if there's a faster way to do this, using numpy or cython?

I'm not very familiar with cython but i tried implementing this way, compiled it and all but I got an error.

```
def andinclude(list main_list,list temp_list):
    and_include=[]
    for sett in main_list:
        if set(temp_list).issubset(sett):
            and_include.append(sett)
    return and_include
```

Hopefully there's a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np

# Randomly generate 2d array of integers
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=(13000000, 6))

# Use numpy indexing to filter rows
results = a[(a == 4).any(axis=1) & (a == 5).any(axis=1)]
```

**Results:**

```
In [35]: print(results.shape)
(3053198, 6)

In [36]: print(results[:5])
[[5 5 4 5 5 1]
 [5 5 4 3 8 6]
 [2 5 8 1 1 4]
 [0 5 4 1 1 5]
 [3 2 5 2 4 6]]
```

**Timing:**

```
In [37]: %timeit results = a[(a == 4).any(axis=1) & (a == 5).any(axis=1)]
923 ms ± 38.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If you need your results converted back to a list of lists rather than a 2d numpy array, you can use:

```
l = results.tolist()
```

This added about 50% to the time taken to run on my machine, but should still be faster than any solution involving looping over Python lists.

Comment: If he got list, isn't it slower to convert everything to numpy, then convert it back to list? The inputs are list and not numpy array (But I strongly agree with you, for performance, the lists should ba voided)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken that's a valid point, thanks. If OP is forced to start with a list of lists as described then my solution is no good. I was hoping that OP would be able to import their dataset (wherever it is coming from) directly into a NumPy array instead, but maybe that isn't possible. I'll wait and see if OP comments before deciding whether I should keep/remove/edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension instead of appending in the loop. Also, you might want to store the result of `set(temp_list)` in a local variable so you're not calling `set` 13 million times for the same result.